# How do I migrate Yii2 passwords?

Tags: 9, migrations

I migrated users from Yii2 to Drupal 9, where there are password hashes like *$2y$13$nhBZ37OKp27jJBLgRkFlOuL5ac8Bda5n2XIZTjKON5gKPfIcxh61y* genereated by Yii2 with `\Yii::$app->security->generatePasswordHash("123qweASD"))`.

I migrated them 1:1.

[Migrating users - advanced password examples](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/migrate-api/migrate-destination-plugins-examples/migrating-users-advanced-password#s-migrating-password-hashes-generated-%20with-crypt-or-password-hash) says:

> If the source system was a PHP based application that used crypt() or password_hash(), these hashes should work as-is and they can be migrated 1:1 like in the Phpass example above .When the user logs in to your Drupal 8 site for the first time, Drupal will re-hash the password.

The password are not correct.

I tried to manually insert various hashes into the database according to this algorithm (crypt() with costFactor 13) generated in Yii2, but this also leads to a login error.

I found the following code in Yii2 (User.php).

```php
/**
 * Validates password
 *
 * @param string $password password to validate
 * @return boolean if password provided is valid for current user
 */
public function validatePassword($password)
{
    if(!$password) return false;
    return Yii::$app->security->validatePassword($password, $this->password);
}
```

In Security.php, it uses the following code.

```php
/**
 * Verifies a password against a hash.
 * @param string $password The password to verify.
 * @param string $hash The hash to verify the password against.
 * @return boolean whether the password is correct.
 * @throws InvalidParamException on bad password/hash parameters or if crypt() with Blowfish hash is not available.
 * @throws InvalidConfigException when an unsupported password hash strategy is configured.
 * @see generatePasswordHash()
 */
public function validatePassword($password, $hash)
{
    if (!is_string($password) || $password === '') {
        throw new InvalidParamException('Password must be a string and cannot be empty.');
    }

    if (!preg_match('/^\$2[axy]\$(\d\d)\$[\.\/0-9A-Za-z]{22}/', $hash, $matches) || $matches[1] < 4 || $matches[1] > 30) {
        throw new InvalidParamException('Hash is invalid.');
    }

    switch ($this->passwordHashStrategy) {
        case 'password_hash':
            if (!function_exists('password_verify')) {
                throw new InvalidConfigException('Password hash key strategy "password_hash" requires PHP >= 5.5.0, either upgrade your environment or use another strategy.');
            }
            return password_verify($password, $hash);
        case 'crypt':
            $test = crypt($password, $hash);
            $n = strlen($test);
            if ($n !== 60) {
                return false;
            }
            return $this->compareString($test, $hash);
        default:
            throw new InvalidConfigException("Unknown password hash strategy '{$this->passwordHashStrategy}'");
    }
}
```

Yii 2.0.6 runs on PHP 5.6, while Drupal 9.4.5 runs on PHP 8.1.4.

How do I migrate password hashes?

Comment: Here is the check function: https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/-/blob/9.4.x/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Password/PhpassHashedPassword.php#L221. Setting aside the documentation page for a moment, it is evident why a hash that begins with `$2y$13$` can't be checked.

Comment: @cilefen
Thx. How do I make this migration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That doc page seems to apply to Drupal 10, not Drupal 9.
see: https://www.drupal.org/node/3322420

If you need to use Drupal 9 you could backport the code and/or write your own class the implements the same interface as

```
Drupal\Core\Password\PhpassHashedPassword
```

In Drupal 9 core.services.yml you wold need to swap your replacement class for that one in the core service definition.

```
service:
  password:
    class: Drupal\Core\Password\PhpassHashedPassword
    arguments: [16]
```

Altering is covered in the doc below, though there is a simpler way of using a replacement definition in the services file in sites/default/services.yml

https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/services-and-dependency-injection/altering-existing-services-providing-dynamic-services

Comment: The documentation linked in the Question offers instructions for the same: https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/migrate-api/migrate-destination-plugins-examples/migrating-users-advanced-password#s-preserving-passwords-hashed-with-another-algorithm